# Regexp_replace for JSON

Tags: regex, regexp-replace

How to regexp_replace the phone_num & phone_ext with only numeric instead of characters.

```
[ {
  "phone_type":"HOME",
  "phone_num":"(+1)123-456-7890",
  "phone_ext":"-85254-",
  "phone_status":"Y",
 },
  {
  "phone_type":"HOME",
  "phone_num":"+001-123-456-7890",
  "phone_ext":"85-254",
  "phone_status":"N",
 }
]
```

should be displayed as

```
[ {
  "phone_type":"HOME",
  "phone_num":"11234567890",
  "phone_ext":"85254",
  "phone_status":"Y",
 },
  {
  "phone_type":"HOME",
  "phone_num":"0011234567890",
  "phone_ext":"85254",
  "phone_status":"N",
 }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, finding the text is fairly easy.

```
/phone_(num|ext)"\s*:\s*"([^"]*)",/gmi
```

Next part is finding the second grouping ([^"]*) within your match function and strip all none numeric characters.  This will vary by application.

Comment: Thanks for the update Vince. I am trying in SQL ( Hive / Oracle ) but I could not able to get it. Any help much appreciated.